# android wifi direction by two mimo antennas

Tags: android, wifi, direction, wifimanager

In the context of an Android App, 
I'm looking for a way to get informations from sigle antenna of MIMO antennas, it's important to evaluate the direction of wifi signal.

It seems that Android APIs provide only the possibility to get information about BSSID, SSID,and signal strength, but nothing about informations from sigle antenna of MIMO antennas.

Has anyone some ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: MIMO antennas have a separate connection for each antenna. Each antenna is often polarized differently... for example orthogonal to each other (90 degrees of rotation) so they can easily be distinguished as separate signals by the receiver elsewhere. So to connect just one of the antennas should be identical to just connecting to a regular old single antenna.